# What does require_self mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sprockets

In rails3.1 `application.css` we could see

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
*/
```

I know that `require_tree .` is just telling the system to bundle together everything from the stylesheets folder into a single file.

But what does `require_self` tells?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html:

```
/* ...
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/
```

"In this example **require_self is used. This will put the CSS contained within the file (if any) at the top of any other CSS in this file unless require_self is specified after another require directive.**"

Comment: and with one, tiny, should-have-been-obvious change, all my styles start working.  Gratze

Answer (score 21):

Shedd's answer used to be correct but now the meaning has changed ever so slightly;

Again, from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html (bolding my own):

> In this example require_self is used. This puts the CSS contained within the file (if any) **at the precise location of the require_self call**. If require_self is called more than once, only the last call is respected.

So you can have `require_self` at any point, and any CSS you have in the file will be injected into the point you wrote `require_self`

Answer (score 14):

```
//= require_self
```

It loads the file itself, to define the order that the files are loaded.