# Sass mixin defined at vendor/assets/stylesheets/external.scss file not getting found by Rails 4

Tags: sass, ruby-on-rails-4

Its a Rails 4 project.
In the file `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss`, I've

```
/*
 *= require_self
 */
@mixin row() {
  color: blue;
}

body {
  h1 {
    @include row;
  }
}
```

Starting the server and viewing in the browser works fine.

Now I take that mixin and put in the file `vendor/assets/stylesheets/external.scss`

```
@mixin row() {
  color: blue;
}
```

and require it in the `application.css.scss` as the following:

```
/*
 *= require external
 *= require_self
 */

body {
  h1 {
     @include row;
  }
}
```

And refresh the browser, it errors out with

```
Sass::SyntaxError 
Undefined mixin 'row'.
```

Why is the mixin defined in the external file is not working??

Answer (score 0):

this might not be very helpful for your error, but from [the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) it says:

> In this example require_self is used. This puts the CSS contained
>   within the file (if any) at the precise location of the require_self
>   call. If require_self is called more than once, only the last call is
>   respected.

it is also discussed in this answer: [What does require_self mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407067/what-does-require-self-mean)

Comment: definitely its not helpful for the error i m facing. want the solution addressing the problem. I'd also tried deleting the `require_self` line and adding in the separate file and requiring it manually too.

Comment: did you try renaming the file? maybe there is another resource named the same way?

Comment: which file your are talking to rename about?

Comment: the `external` file. the name is pretty generic, so there might be some other file shadowing this.

Comment: nop, i dont think so. coz before renaming to `external`, it was `landing`, I renamed on purpose as an example only.