# Why is require_tree before require_self in default application.css?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I noticed that after generating a new Rails 4.2 application the order for the requires in **application.css** has been changed.

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
```

Shouldn't this be the other way around? Even in the [Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) it isn't this way...

Comment: I don't have an official line I can quote at the moment, but I believe `require_self` literally includes the manifest file itself and any JS or CSS you've included in body of the file, but the rest of the manifest merely indicates which files to load. You can remove `require_self` and still have a normally running application. So in short, you can reverse those lines, or leave it as it, or remove `require_self` if you want, it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @PaulRichter It does make a difference,I think . In my application I have explicitly defined the position on top , if I remove it ,the application.css file gets to the bottom and override css rules defined .

Comment: @shail I'm not sure I fully understand what you described, but yes when I implied "the position doesn't matter", I was mistaken.  If you take a look at my answer below I corrected that statement based on some research I found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The change was made in order to allow styles defined in `application.css` to override previously included styles.

See [Rails issue #11639](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11639) and [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/f18aecfe7b70849f2f73da329a6a14260cea6edd) which changed the order of the `require` instructions.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the official documentation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives), and also explained in this SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6413583/877472):

> This puts the CSS contained within the file (if any) at the precise location of the require_self call.

This is slightly different than what I wrote in the comments since, as indicated by the above quote, the JS or CSS in the manifest will be inserted at the location of `require_self`. This becomes important if you have later assets that depend on something you wrote in the manifest.

Of course if you're doing that though, it would probably be better to place that "inline" asset in a separate file anyways, just to keep the manifest clean.

Comment: and janfoeh's answer explains why it was "reversed" like that in that version of Rails, which I didn't know.